# jQuery.. pulling a string before current element

Tags: jquery, element, row, pull

HTML..

```
<div class="row">
   <div>
      <b>Title A</b> <a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   </div>
   Content A
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div>
      <b>Title B</b> <a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   </div>
   Content B
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div>
      <b>Title C</b> <a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   </div>
   Content C
</div>
```

jQuery..

So far my JS adds a "Link 3" link after each "Link 2"..

```
$("a:contains('Link 2')").each(function(){
   $(this).after(' <a href="#">Link 3</a>');
});
```

**For each item in the loop how would I access the title.**

```
$("a:contains('Link 2')").each(function(){
   // I need to find the title string for each row. So is there a way to find elements before the $(this) identifier?
   $(this).after(' <a href="#">Link 3</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the previous sibling by using the [.prev() method](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev#expr). You can do that, or you can get the links [.parent()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent#expr), and then [.find()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr) the first `<b>` tag.

```
<p>Something Here</p> <!-- This becomes red -->
<p class="pickme">Hello World</p>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".pickme").prev().css("color","red");
});
```

or

```
<p>Something Here</p> <!-- this becomes green -->
<p class="pickme">Hello World</p>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".pickme").parent().find("p:first").css("color", "green");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a class, such as "rowTitle" to all of your bold tags that are wrapping your titles, you should be able to do:

```
$("a:contains('Link 2')").each(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".rowTitle").html
});
```

Or something fairly similar.  The [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) are fairly comprehensive, and a quick search there should help you find what you're looking for.

I'm not a jQuery expert, but I believe that's fairly close to working.  Perhaps someone a bit more versed in the matter could elaborate on my answer (as I wouldn't mind learning as well).